# SSRS And Expression not working

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005, ssrs-expression

I have an expression in SSRS like this.

```
IIF(First(Fields!val.Value, "box29")="Yes" AND Sum(Fields!SortOrder.Value, "InsuranceInformation") > 1,"",
```

Valu val is Yes and Sortorder is 2. That is both expression satisfying. But this expression is not satisfying with AND. 
Any idea on this?

Comment: are you getting error or are you getting output for false

Comment: can you please post the whole expression and errors if any or what the expression is returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to finish your expression:

```
=IIF(First(Fields!val.Value, "box29")="Yes" And Sum(Fields!SortOrder.Value, "InsuranceInformation") > 1, "And expession statisfyed", "And expression not statisfyed")
```